# Text between two dollar signs JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use RegEx to select all strings between two dollar signs.

```
text = text.replace(/\$.*\$/g, "meow");
```

I'm trying to turn all text between two dollar signs into "meow" (placeholder).

**EDIT:**
Original question changed because the solution was too localized, but the accepted answer is useful information.

Comment: Assuming text is just a string, there's nothing wrong with what you have: http://jsfiddle.net/JAuSy/1/

Comment: Are you shure you don't want `replace(/\$[^\$]*\$/g, "meow");` ?

Comment: Ok, forget my other comments.  Now I know what this does.  Good call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty close to what you want, but it will fail if you have multiple pairs of `$text$` in your string.  If you make your `.*` repeater lazy, it will fix that. E.g.,

```
text = text.replace(/\$.*?\$/g, "meow");
```

Comment: +1 didn't know about this. I would have used `[^\$]*`

Comment: Thanks!  This essentially prevents mismatch from $'s as delimiters, right?

Comment: This does solve one problem I might have in the future, but it still isn't working.  I think it's something to do with the original text processing in the file.

Comment: @jandjorgensen can you please give as a not working example? (In order we get to see what should be the result)

Comment: Hmm... I think we would have to see what the raw input looks like. Also it's possible you have some new lines messing with you.  Can you provide a sample of the text as it is immediately prior to running the regular expression?

Comment: very interesting, i don't know this form. But I need to warn Bennika about the [ ] construct: you can use [^$] without the \ because every character inside a [ list ] is a literal character (except for the first ^ and the ]

Comment: I found the problem in the other code.  There's a input sanitizing function that I needed to add to to enable using it as a tag.  Trying to decide what I should do as far as accepting an answer.

Comment: Actually, here it is:
            // attacklab: Replace $ with ~D
            // RegExp interprets $ as a special character
            // when it's in a replacement string
            text = text.replace(/\$/g, "~D");

I'm going to change the question a bit and accept this as the answer because I think it's a really useful one.

Comment: I was going to flag to close since my situation was too unique to be meaningful to future users, but I thought your solution was something someone searching might be interested in.

Answer (score 3):

I see one problem: if you have more than one "template" like

aasdasdsadsdsa $a$ dasdasdsd $b$ asdasdasdsa

your regular expression will consider '$a$ dasdasdsd $b$' as a text between two dolar signals. you can use a less specific regular expression like

/\$[^$]*\$/g

to consider two strings in this example

Comment: This was already mentioned two times.

Comment: No, about 6-7 minutes before you answered. :D

Comment: I'm writing and dont see the other message. sorry.

Comment: +1, because your's is right (I had `[^\$]`, didn't know about the wrong \\)

Comment: it is not wrong, but your list will consider the character \ too :)

Comment: or it can be a "open minded" RegExp :)