# Regex replace pair of dollar signs

Tags: php, regex, markdown, mathjax

I have combined **MathJax** and **Markdown** markup and therefore I need to replace all `$$` with `<span>$$</span>` so that Markdown don't render $$_^... signs from MathJax. Also all `\[ \]` must be replaced with `<div>\[ \]</div>`.

I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556373/text-between-two-dollar-signs-javascript-regex) but it's not exactly what I need. I need to convert this

```
This is $some$ math \[equation\] which I $like$.
```

to this

```
This is <span>$some$</span> math <div>\[equation\]</div> which I <span>$like$</span>.
```

Probably what I need to to is just in regex

```
text = text.replace(/\$.*?\$/g, "meow");
```

somehow include and `$$` signs (or `\[ \]`) and just with `$1` embed the text inside `<span>$$1$</span>` and adapt to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps because the replacement texts are different.

First, replace the `$..$`:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\$.*?\$/', '<span>\0</span>', $text);
```

Then, replace the `\[...\]`:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\\\\\[.*?\\\\\]/', '<div>\0</div>', $text);
```

Comment: The second one also caches double backslash as a replacement and from `Test \\ Blah` I get `Test <div>\\</div> Blah`. Also I'm using PHP equivalents `/(\$.*?\$)/, "<span>$1</span>"` and `/(\\\[.*?\\\])/, "<div>$1</div>"`.

Comment: @svenkapudija: I'm not following. You're using those in JavaScript, right? The second one shouldn't be capturing "\\" because the `\[` is mandatory.

Comment: PHP actually, my fault, now I added the tag to the question. I removed the javascript escapes and it doesn't mark double backslash but neither the `\[ \]` signs - `/(\[.*?\])/`

Comment: @svenkapudija: OK, in that case you need to change the regex because PHP needs four backslashes in a regex to match a single literal backslash. (And use `\0` instead of `$&`.) See my edit.

Comment: Got it! Also needed `/s` modifier at the end for multiple lines (overlooked that one). Thanks.

Comment: I need one additional requirement, it should do this replacement but only if the character before $ is not `\\` (backslash). So $test$ should be replaced but not \$test\$.

Comment: @svenkapudija: I suspect the problem is more complicated - you need to check for an odd number of backslashes.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but for now this basic solution will work just fine.